# Java:multidimensional array problem

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

In a multidimensional array, is it possible to use the length variable to 
measure different dimensions other than the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Length dimensions vary from row to row. You can do `matrix[i].length` to get the length of row `i`. If you know the matrix is square, all the row lengths will equals `matrix[0].length` anyways, so it doesn't matter.

If you're trying to iterate through all elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    for(int j < 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
        count += matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

The same principle can be applied for any number of dimensions. For loops, you need 1 nested loop per dimension. For lengths, each bracketed part is actually a new element, so 3d array `ar` will yield a 2d array with `ar[i]`, 1d with `ar[i][j]`, and 0d (single element of the array type) with `ar[i][j][k]`

Comment: Nice that you point out that Java's memory structure is an arrays of arrays (of arrays... etc) for multiple dimension arrays, instead of the traditional C model.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    long[][][] multi = new long[3][2][1];
    System.out.println(multi.length); //3
    System.out.println(multi[0].length); //2
    System.out.println(multi[0][0].length); //1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
array.length;
array[0].length;
array[1].length;
```

Comment: This doesn't really fully explain that array[0] and array[1] can be of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, you need `array[0].length` to get size of second dimension, and `array[0][0].length` to get length of third. Of course, arrays are not matrices, so `array[0].length` and `array[1].length` might be different, depending on the sizes of the sub-arrays you stored at `array[0]` resp. `array[1]`

Comment: If the matrix is square, `array[i]` will be the same for all `i < array.length`. If the matrix isn't square, `array[0].length` tells you nothing except that the `length` value for the first array is X.